# is it possible to make a reflection sit at infinity, like a reflex sight or a HUD?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, light

i want to simulate an effect such as a heads up display and tried to recreate it simply, through the use of light projecting through a reticle, through a convex lens, and onto a pane of glass seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflector_sight). the light definitely reflects onto the glass, but doesn't stay in the same position when i move my view port.

this is the full scene
[image: full scene]

these are two angles, compared to each other the light definitely does *not* stay in the same place
[image: angle 1]

[image: angle 2]

i realize this could totally just be a limitation in blender, or a simple mistake in my scene, but clarification or tips would be helpful!

Comment: I would like to use *transparent + glossy shader* in the reflection glass. And the lens below need to be a perfect Refractive len as well.

Comment: Do you need to simulate it or would it be enough to fake it with compositing?

Comment: Wouldn't a heads up display *move **with** the camera*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the wiki page said, you need your lens to refract parallel light.

### Key Points

- the lens need to be perfect refraction lens or it will cause distortion
- the iron sight laser thing need to on the exatly same position of the lens focus point
- the reflective plane should be 45 degree above the lens

### Workflow

You can create a nearly perfect refraction lens by intersect two ball.
[image: Lens]

After the lens is setup, you need to know its focus length. It can be done several ways. I use a sun light with orthogonal view to tune the point on a plane:

[image: Focus point]

You need to change parameter in render panel, for those thing will clamp indirect light, turn it off to get accurate result.

And last thing, your 45 degree reflective glass need to be fully transparent without distortion, recommend to use transparent shader + Glossy shader, and place above the lens correctly:

[image: Setting]

Then the result can be stable in sight with slightly distortion:
[image: 2]
[image]

The full scene is extremely complicated in rendering, consider something else.

And for the file I test for it in Blender 2.80: [image]